# Inheritence and usage of dynamic_cast

Tags: c++, inheritance, oop, dynamic-cast

Suppose I have 3 classes as follows (as this is an example, it will not compile!):

```
class Base
{
public:
   Base(){}
   virtual ~Base(){}
   virtual void DoSomething() = 0;
   virtual void DoSomethingElse() = 0;
};

class Derived1
{
public:
   Derived1(){}
   virtual ~Derived1(){}
   virtual void DoSomething(){ ... }
   virtual void DoSomethingElse(){ ... }
   virtual void SpecialD1DoSomething{ ... }
};

class Derived2
{
public:
   Derived2(){}
   virtual ~Derived2(){}
   virtual void DoSomething(){ ... }
   virtual void DoSomethingElse(){ ... }
   virtual void SpecialD2DoSomething{ ... }
};
```

I want to create an instance of Derived1 or Derived2 depending on some setting that is not available until run-time.

As I cannot determine the derived type until run-time, then do you think the following is bad practice?...

```
class X
{
public:
   ....

   void GetConfigurationValue()
   {
      ....
      // Get configuration setting, I need a "Derived1"
      b = new Derived1();

      // Now I want to call the special DoSomething for Derived1
      (dynamic_cast<Derived1*>(b))->SpecialD1DoSomething();      
   }
private:
   Base* b;
};
```

I have generally read that usage of dynamic_cast is bad, but as I said, I don't know
which type to create until run-time. Please help!

Comment: Assuming there are some specific options that differ for the methods SpecialD1DoSomething, SpecialD2DoSomething  so that you can't just name them the same and call it on the base.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using dynamic_cast is not bad practice per se. It's bad practice to use it inappropriately, i.e. where it's not really needed.

It's also a bad practice to use it this way:

```
(dynamic_cast<Derived1*>(b))->SpecialD1DoSomething();
```

Reason: dynamic_cast(b) may return NULL.

When using dynamic_cast, you have to be extra careful, because it's not guaranteed, that b is actually of type Derived1 and not Derived2:

```
void GenericFunction(Base* p)
{
    (dynamic_cast<Derived1*>(b))->SpecialD1DoSomething();
}

void InitiallyImplementedFunction()
{
   Derived1 d1;
   GenericFunction(&d1); // OK... But not for long. 
   // Especially, if implementation of GenericFunction is in another library
   // with not source code available to even see its implementation 
   // -- just headers
}    

void SomeOtherFunctionProbablyInAnotherUnitOfCompilation()
{
   Derived2 d2;
   GenericFunction(&d2); // oops!
}
```

You have to check if dynamic_cast is actually successful. There are two ways of doing it: checking it before and after the cast. Before the cast you can check if the pointer you're trying to cast is actually the one you expect via RTTI:

```
if (typeid(b) == typeid(Derived1*))
{
   // in this case it's safe to call the function right 
   // away without additional checks
   dynamic_cast<Derived1*>(b)->SpecialD1DoSomething();
}
else
{
  // do something else, like try to cast to Derived2 and then call
  // Derived2::SpecialD2DoSomething() in a similar fashion
}
```

Checking it post-factum is actually a bit simpler:

```
Derived1* d1 = dynamic_cast<Derived1*>(b);
if (d1 != NULL)
{
   d1->SpecialD1DoSomething();
}
```

I'd also say it's a bad practice to try and save typing while programming in C++. There are many features in C++ than seem to be completely fine to be typed shorter (i.e. makes you feel 'that NULL will never happen here'), but turn out to be a pain in the ass to debug afterwards. ;)

Answer (score 7):

Why not delay the moment at which you "throw away" some if the type information by assigning a pointer to derived to a pointer to base:

```
void GetConfigurationValue()
{
  // ...
  // Get configuration setting, I need a "Derived1"
  Derived1* d1 = new Derived1();
  b = d1;

  // Now I want to call the special DoSomething for Derived1
  d1->SpecialD1DoSomething();
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The point of virtual functions is that once you have the right kind of object, you can call the right function *without* knowing which derived class this object is -- you just call the virtual function, and it does the right thing.

You only need a `dynamic_cast` when you have a derived class that defines something different that's *not* present in the base class, *and* you need/want to take the extra something into account.

For example:

```
struct Base { 
    virtual void do_something() {}
};

struct Derived : Base { 
    virtual void do_something() {} // override dosomething
    virtual void do_something_else() {} // add a new function
};
```

Now, if you just want to call `do_something()`, a `dynamic_cast` is completely unnecessary. For example, you can have a collection of `Base *`, and just invoke `do_something()` on every one, without paying any attention to whether the object is really a `Base` or a `Derived`.

When/if you have a `Base *`, and you want to invoke `do_something_else()`, *then* you can use a `dynamic_cast` to figure out whether the object itself is really a `Derived` so you can invoke that.

Answer (score 2):

Some other things you might like to consider to avoid the use of dynamic_cast

From Effective C++ (Third Edition) - Item 35 Alternatives to virtual functions -

1. 'Template Method pattern' via Non-Vitual Interface (NVI). Making the virtual functions private/protected with a public method 'wrapper' - allows you to enforce some other workflow of stuff to do before and after the virtual method.
2. 'Strategy pattern' via function pointers. Pass in the extra method as a function pointer.
3. 'Strategy pattern' via tr1::function. similar to 2. but you could provide whole classes with various options
4. 'Strategy pattern' classic. Seperate Strategy from main class - push the virtual functions into another hierarchy.

Answer (score 1):

What is wrong with:

```
Base * b;
if( some_condition ) {
   b = new Derived1;
}
else {
   b = new Derived2;
}

if ( Derived2 * d2 = dynamic_cast <Derived2 *>( b ) ) {
    d2->SpecialD2DoSomething();
}
```

Or am I missing something?

And can OI suggest that when posting questions like this you (and others) name your classes A, B, C etc.  and your functions things like f1(), f2() etc. It makes life a lot easier for people answering your questions.

Comment: Well, that was the plan. But is the usage of dynamic_cast bad afterwards?

Comment: @Mewzer What do you mean by "bad"? The code in my example is perfectly valid C++, and does what dynamic_cast was designed to do.

Comment: @Neil Butterworth Thank you for your answer - I take on board your comment about simpler names and will use them in the future. By "bad", I meant is it bad practice to use dynamic_cast?. I am a little confused as it appears that the general opinion on dynamic casting is poor (after reading many different posts), and I could not think of a solution that does not use dynamic casts.

Comment: @Mewzer I use it when I need to - and dealing with input (as from a config file) is one of those areas where you sometimes need to.

Comment: I hope that people don't see Neil's "perfectly valid C++" remark being the same as "it compiles". Because Mewser's code in the original question is also valid per C++ syntax, but it is not 'good', because it doesn't make sanity checks, which are critical here. Neil's code does, but it also exploits a feature of C++, that is usually deemed to be a "bad coding practice" -- using assignment in "if". Now, the particular usage here together with a declaration is actually acceptable, I think.

Answer (score 1):

There is a pattern named [Factory Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern) that would fit this scenario.  This allows you to return an instance of the correct class based on some input parameter.

Enjoy!

Answer (score 1):

One way to avoid `dynamic_cast` is to have a virtual trampoline function "SpecialDoSomething" whose derived polymorphic implementation calls that particular derived class's "SpecialDxDoSomething()" which can be whatever non-base class name you desire.  It can even call more than one function.