# Vector of elements from multiple classes that have the same base class

Tags: c++, qt, vector, casting, derived-class

I am currently working on a projekt in which I need a vector of objects from multiple classes, that share the same basic class, so that later on I can invoke methods from it. Let's say my classes look like this:

```
class basicClass
{
public:
  void seta(bool a);
  basicClass();
private:
  int a;
};

class derivedClass1 : public basicClass
{
int b;
public:
  derivedClass1();
  void methodInClass1();
};

class derivedClass2 : public basicClass
{
int c;
public:
  derivedClass2();
  void methodInClass2();
};
```

Then in main.cpp i would like to invoke the following methods.

```
QVector<basicClass*> vectorINeed;
derviedClass1 *object= new derviedClass1();

qDebug() << object->basicClass::seta(true);
qDebug() << object->derivedClass1::methodInClass1();

vectorINeed.append(object);

qDebug() << vectorINeed[0]->basicClass::seta(true);
qDebug() << vectorINeed[0]->derivedClass1::methodInClass1();
```

And even thought I see that the first three work perfectly fine, the last one does not and the error i get is "derivedClass1' is not a base of 'basicClass'". Is there any way fix my classes so that I can actually do the things i want? I tried to change the methods in basicClass to virtual but that doesn't solve the problem and I also tried some casting but either I did something wrong or it's not a way to solve my issue.

I would really appreciate any help, even hints on what could be helpful. Also I hope the editing is ok.

Comment: Related (near duplicate): http://stackoverflow.com/q/3065200/179910

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you give a copy of `DerivedClass` into a vector containing pointers of `BaseClass`, you're essentially downcasting the pointer inside the vector to a `BaseClass` object, meaning that that you lose all the `DerivedClass` type information (methods, members, etc). While the `DerivedClass` contents will still be there, they'll no longer be accessible.

Take the following example:

```
class MyBaseClass
{
public:
  MyBaseClass();
  virtual ~MyBaseClass();

  void SetValue(const int value);
  int GetValue() const;

private:
  int m_value;
};


class MyDerivedClass : public MyBaseClass
{
public:
  MyDerivedClass();
  virtual ~MyDerivedClass();

  void SetExtraValue(const std::string &value);
  std::string GetExtraValue() const;

private:
  std::string m_extraValue;
};
```

Every variable created of "MyBaseClass" only guarantees that the `SetValue` and `GetValue` methods are available. Every variable created of MyDerivedClass guarantees that 4 methods are available, the two methods from the base class, and the `SetExtraValue` and `GetExtraValue` methods.

If you create a vector of `MyBaseClass` pointers, you're only guaranteeing that the methods `SetValue` and `GetValue` are going to be available on the contents of that vector, EVEN IF THE CONTENTS ARE ALL `MyDerivedClass`.

Consider this modified version of your example:

```
QVector<basicClass*> vectorINeed;
basicClass *object= new basicClass();  // <--- Create basicClass instance instead of derivedClass1 instance.

qDebug() << object->basicClass::seta(true);

vectorINeed.append(object);

qDebug() << vectorINeed[0]->basicClass::seta(true);
qDebug() << vectorINeed[0]->derivedClass1::methodInClass1(); // <--- What would happen here?
```

The compiler cannot guarantee that the object inside the vector is a `derivedClass1` object, only a `basicClass` object, therefore it cannot guarantee that the `methodInClass1` method will be available.

As I see it, you've got three options:

1. Change the vector declaration to `QVector<derivedClass1 *> vectorINeed` if you can. Or...
2. Run your methods against `object` rather than `vectorINeed[0]`.
3. If you can guarantee that the contents of the vector will ALWAYS be of type `derivedClass1`, you can use the `dynamic_cast` function to perform a cast to derivedType before doing `methodInClass1`.

Answer (score 0):

Although you are able to add derived classes to a vector of base classes, the vector is still of base classes.

Therefore, in effect, you are "casting" (I say casting but it's not quite) to a baseclass before adding to the vector.

To use a derived classes methods from a base class vector you'd want to make sure you are dealing with a derived class (maybe a get method with a static variable which is assigned at creation). Then cast the object in the vector back to the necessary derived class before using the function.

There may be a better way, but I need to brush up on my C++